# woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data being called 3 times

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

I am writing a plugin for Woocommerce to do an api call to a coupon provider and I'm hooking into `woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data` with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', 'wigroup_coupon_injecion', 1, 3  );
```

All is working as expected, **but this hook is called 3 times on each page load**, as well as when a coupon is entered, or removed.

So my question:

How to hook into the coupon being applied other than `woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data`?

Is it normal for it being called 3 times each time?

Just on a side note on the woocommerce Cart, I need a unique Identifier for each cart. I do understand there is only a unique identifier when the order is completed, But I need to pass a identifier to each coupon transaction.

Any ideas there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better track customer events related to coupons instead:

1. When customer **apply a coupon code** using `woocommerce_applied_coupon` action hook:

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'action_applied_coupon', 10, 1 );
   function action_applied_coupon( $coupon_code ) {
       // Your code here
   }
   ```
2. When customer **remove a coupon code** using `woocommerce_removed_coupon` action hook:

   ```
   add_action('woocommerce_removed_coupon', 'action_removed_coupon', 10, 1 );
   function action_removed_coupon( $coupon_code ) {
       // Your code here
   }
   ```

This hooks will be called one time only for each customer event regarding coupons…

Comment: Oky so this works fine, only thing is, I need to fire my api, check if the coupon is valid, create the coupon programmatically and then apply it. woocommerce_applied_coupon will first try and apply the coupon (which does not exist) then only do the api call

Comment: @BGSmit Remember that this hooks are only fired on customer coupon event action…

Comment: Yes I understand that, And it is exactly the structure we need. We can only do a voucher validation when they submit it, that is why we need to almost intercept the coupon process, and add our own logic